# List selected options in Selenium Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to list the selected options from the page. But nothing is printed with below code. Any help will be appreciated.

HTML code:

```
<select class="chosen-select" id="tag_opts" name="tag_opts[]" tabindex="-1" multiple="true" data-placeholder="Select a call tag here" disabled="disabled">
<optgroup label="TAGS">
    <option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
    <option value="2" selected="selected">2</option>
    <option value="3" selected="selected">3</option>
    <option value="4" selected="selected">4</option>                      
</optgroup>
</select>
```

What I tried:

```
  el = driver.find_element_by_id("tag_opts")
  for option in el.find_elements_by_tag_name('option'):
     if option.text in labels:
     print(option)
```

I tried with many other options but couldn't succeed.

Comment: Is the html code hasn't been loaded when you scraped it?

Comment: Above code is contained in `frame`. When I list all `page_source` code, above options are displayed. So it seems that html code is loaded.

Comment: You need to switch to the `frame` first.

Comment: Yes, I've done that.

Comment: please post all of your code.. `labels` is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Select` to handle `<select>` elements :

```
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("tag_opts"))
options = select.options
for option in options:
 print(option.text)     #or print(option.get_attribute("value"))
```

Comment: Shivam, with `print(option.get_attribute("value"))`, it worked. You may edit answer.  Thank you.

Comment: @Experimenter, Even though it didn't work for you,`.text` is a solution too so I would keep my answer as it is(with both the solutions) :)

Comment: Ok. Thank you for confirming.

Answer (score 0):

Just comment out the 'if' statement and print(option.text)

```
el = driver.find_element_by_id("tag_opts")
for option in el.find_elements_by_tag_name('option'):
   #if option.text in labels:
   print(option.text)
```

PS your if statement refers to a 'labels' object that isn't defined. So it will never match anything

Comment: I'll try it out.

Comment: With above changes, just 4 blank lines are printed in console.